# Removing environment from PyCharm skeleton generator

Tags: python, pycharm

I tried to add an Ananconda environment in PyCharm, but when the skeleton generator runs on this new environment, I get a Windows error that Python has crashed on an infinite loop (it seems to be a problem with PyQt).

I removed that defective environment from my list of interpreters and closed PyCharm. But on reopening, the skeleton generator still inspects that environment and triggers the crash.  If I go into the list of interpreters, the environment is not there. Is there somewhere else where this environment is listed in PyCharm?  How can I remove it from the skeleton generator?